# Save a vector in a .csv file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]'` of size `6 x 1`.

I want to save this vector in a `.csv file`, but I want that my `.csv file` to be like:
[image]

I wrote this code in MATLAB:

```
csvwrite('my_file.csv', y)
```

How can I edit my code in order to get as the file above?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming `y` is a column vector)

```
dlmwrite('my_file.csv',[[1:length(y)]',y])
```

For example,

```
y=rand(10,1)
dlmwrite('my_file.csv',[[1:length(y)]',y])
```

and now the content of `my_file.csv` looks,

```
1,0.70605
2,0.031833
3,0.27692
4,0.046171
5,0.097132
6,0.82346
7,0.69483
8,0.3171
9,0.95022
10,0.034446
```

if your original vector is a row (not a column) looks a bit easier,

```
y=rand(1,10)
dlmwrite('my_file.csv',[1:length(y);y]')
```

Also, if you want the header also on the file you can do like this,

```
y=rand(1,10);
name1 = 'InD';
name2 = 'y';

delimiter = ',';
header = [name1, delimiter, name2];
dlmwrite('my_file.csv',header,'delimiter','');
dlmwrite('my_file.csv',[1:length(y);y]','-append','delimiter',delimiter);
```

where you can change `y` for your vector and then define `name1` and `name2` as you prefer.

EDIT:
Just noticed currently MATLAB discourages the use of `dlmwrite`, in that case this is an alternative also,

```
y = rand(1,10);
name1 = 'InD';
name2 = 'y';

header = {name1,name2};
output = [header; num2cell([1:length(y);y]')];
writecell(output,'my_file.csv')
```

Comment: Hello I don't want a txt file. I want a .csv file as mentioned in my question. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I just fixed it. Note that the extension does not determine the content of the file, is just part of the name.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a matrix as following, and save it to the CSV file (below, I used [writematrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) instead of `csvwrite`)

```
y_matrix = [1 0.1; 2 0.2; 3 0.3; 4 0.4; 5 0.5; 6 0.6]
writematrix(y_matrix, 'my_file.csv')
```

You can build this matrix with the strategy you desire; e.g., a matrix may be created by joining two vectors. The first vector can be a range with the length of the second vector.

Comment: Hello no I want only A and B as first line, and then start indexing automatically for each value of y.

Comment: To write the column A, you can do something like `a = 1:length(y);`.

To include headers, you can follow this suggestion: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/246922-how-to-add-headers-to-a-data-matrix

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. I edited it.

Comment: That's ok, I edited my last answer too :)

Comment: I now clarified well what I want. jajaja you are patient on me:)

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, you can create a helper function to write csv with header like this:

```
function to_csv(filename, data, header)
    datatable = array2table(data);
    datatable.Properties.VariableNames(1:length(header)) = header;
    writetable(datatable, filename);
end
```

Usage example:

```
y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]';
InD = (1:length(y))';
to_csv('my_file.csv', [InD, y], ["InD", "y"]);
```